# $H^1_0(M)$ for non-compact $M$

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Consider a complete non-compact Riemannian manifold $M$. My question is, is it possible for a non-zero constant function $c$ to be in $H^1_0(M)$? My guess is, this should be possible when $M$ has finite volume, but I am not sure about this. A little insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of $H^1_0(M)$?